# How can I test required fields in JSON object?

Tags: c#, json, post

I want to verify that a request fails when required properties don't have a value, but am having trouble with the response section. Here is an example of my JSON body:

```
{
    "brand": "",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": ""
}
```

Here is the response I want to validate:

```
{
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "modelState": {
        "request.Brand": [
            "The Brand field is required."
        ],
        "request.FirstName": [
            "The FirstName field is required."
        ],
        "request.LastName": [
            "The LastName field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that a request doesn't go through if the fields above don't have values. Then, I want to verify which fields caused the request to fail.

Thank you.

Comment: I am afraid it is quite unclear what you are asking.

Comment: My apologies for the vagueness. I'm self-taught with automation, and new to APIs, so I sometimes have a hard time getting my point across. I want to make sure that a request doesn't go through if the fields above don't have values. Then, I want to verify which fields caused the request to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend checking out model validation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Essentially creating a C# object and decorating your properties with the necessary validation tags.  You can then force a validation check and respond accordingly all in the controller.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!